# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path using correct syntx

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an asp page c# code behind.

I am trying to save to the server using this line

```
File.Delete(@"C:\Webroot\Intranet\Intranet\Sales\Agreements_Marketing\test.xlsx");
```

I know this is a valid path and a valid file because I can see it on the server.

I don't understand why I am getting this error.

Comment: Does the folder have permissions correct ?

Comment: Is Intranet in there twice on purpose?

Comment: There are two intranet folders?

Comment: Double check the path. DirectoryNotFoundException has been pretty accurate to me ;)

Comment: @JimmyHoffa if it were a Permission issue the exception would be different. I would be very pissed at MS if I get a DirectoryNotFoundException for a Permission issue.

Comment: Yo Dawg! I heard you like Intranets! So we put an Intranet in your Intranet. (sorry)

Comment: @Icarus oops, missed the exception in title.

Comment: So you're saying that if you copy and paste that path into a Run dialog it will open the XLSX file?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the app pool user (which by default, for good reasons, has very restricted permissions) is not allowed to see the file.

Comment: That should give a different exception about permission.